# Cypher query that returns multiple relationships as subsets of each other

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to work with all nodes that are connected by a relationship `r` with an attribute `r.name` that matches a string. But I want to return not only all the nodes that have the relationship, but also a different potential relationship `l` between the nodes returned.

I tried something like

```
MATCH (n) - [r:FIRST_REL] - (m)
WHERE r.name = 'string'
WITH n, r, m
OPTIONAL MATCH (n) -[l:SECOND_REL] - (m)
RETURN r,l
```

but `l` is always `null` although there are nodes returned that are also connected by `SECOND_REL`.

Comment: Try this `RETURN n, m, r, collect(l) as srels ORDER BY size(srels) DESC`

Comment: Your query should work. Can you provide sample data that demonstrates the `NULL` behavior?

Comment: If your second relation is one of your returned columns, and it's a potential relationship (may be there or not), then it's still going to return null for FIRST_REL matches where SECOND_REL does not exist. Can you perhaps clarify what your desired output looks like, and describe it with words so we can avoid confusion?

Comment: I revised the problem, and @cybersam is correct, the query seems to work now. I'm not sure what happened earlier, I'm sorry everyone for the confusion!